# Video Render in NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming, next.js

I'm using NextJS and I was trying to put a video as a background. In the **FIRST** render everything works fine, but when I reload the screen, the video doesn't run in the autoplay mode.

Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import MainHeader from '../components/MainHeader'
import { Container } from '../styles/pages/Home'

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <MainHeader />
      <video autoPlay style={{ width: '500px', height: '500px' }}>
        <source src="/blue.mp4" />
      </video>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Home
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 15):

I have added the loop to your code. I hope it solves your problem

```
import React from 'react'
import MainHeader from '../components/MainHeader'
import { Container } from '../styles/pages/Home'

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
    <MainHeader />
      <video autoPlay loop style={{ width: '500px', height: '500px' }}>
        <source src="/blue.mp4" />
      </video>
    </Container>
   )
 }

export default Home
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for information, the video with sound can't reload even with loop and autoplay, the browser don't allowed.
The solution is put autoplay, loop, muted and controls for could you start the sound if you want.

Comment: The right answer is buried in this one. It's the `muted` attribute that's most important for getting autoplay working.

Answer (score 2):

For playing a video this was working well with Next v12

```
import ReactPlayer from "react-player/lazy";

<ReactPlayer 
width="530px" 
height="300px" 
url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Te_DTmOt4Xw" 
light="/static/normal-sarong-0007.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `muted` attribute in your code, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74896663/476111). That's the most important element for getting past browser autoplay rules.

```
<video autoPlay muted loop style={{ width: '500px', height: '500px' }}>
  <source src="/blue.mp4" />
</video>
```

[This blog post](https://www.mux.com/blog/how-to-add-a-background-video-in-next-js) walks through background videos + next.js in detail.